# Perl remove characters in a string

Tags: perl

I have a $cbDescription variable in a Perl script.  When I print out $cbDescription, I get the following:

```
tIP SOLD -5 /ESH4 @1832.00
```

I want to remove any + or - or @ signs or commas from the string, so I have the following line:

```
$cbDescription =~ s/[+-\@,]//g;
```

I expect that line to change $cbDescription to:

```
tIP SOLD 5 /ESH4 1832.00
```

But when I print out $cbDescription after that line, I get:

```
tIP SOLD  ESH
```

Why did it also remove all the numbers and the decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is a range delimiter in between brackets sou you need to escape it:

```
% echo "tIP SOLD -5 /ESH4 @1832.00" | perl -pi -e 's/[+\-\@,]//g'
tIP SOLD 5 /ESH4 1832.00
```

Comment: You can also specify it as the very first character in the class.